Strapi nuxt3 composable not getting types
So I have a fresh new strapi nuxt3 project up and running and I am trying to create an articles list using the useStrapi composable
This is currently the logic with which I am getting my articles:
const { find } = useStrapi();
const articlesResponse = await find('articles');
let articles = articlesResponse.data;

and then in my template I use this to see my articles:
 <li v-for="article in articles" v-bind:key="article.documentId">
    <pre>  {{ article }}  </pre>

the problem, is that when I try to access article.title, I dont get any intellisense, so it doesnt recognize my types
But I noticed if I type out article.attributes.title, I do get intellisense, but the data I am getting is only accessible by article.title
how do I fix this
I tried adding my type interface to find<Article>('articles') in many different ways but to no avail
